# Twig incrementing values and blocks

Tags: twig

I've got a variable that I'm setting outside of a series of blocks that I want to use as a counter. If I increment the counter inside one block, the subsequent blocks don't see the augmented value. How would I increment a variable so it carries it's value in multiple blocks?

Example:

```
{% block right_column %}
    {% set counter = 0 %}
    {% block navigation %}
        {{ counter }} {# outputs 0 #}
        {# counter should now be 1 #}
        {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
    {% endblock navigation %}

    {% block dynamic_modules %}
        {{ counter }}{# outputs 0 again #}
        {% for module in modules %}
            {# increments as if the navigation block doesn't exist #}
            {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
            {{ counter }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock dynamic_modules %}
{% endblock right_column %}
```

Comment: You can't. Blocks are for separation. If two parts are separated, then why they do depend on each other? Maybe `dynamic_modules` should be part of `navigation`?

Comment: In my perfect world, the navigation block wouldn't exist because it would be curated dynamically like everything in dynamic_modules, but I don't have the authority to decide that. So I'm working with what I have.

Comment: I am sure that carrying variable like that between blocks is impossible. Block cannot change anything outside it. It's how twig works. If someone said you to do so, he want impossible. You can carry values between blocks but you need to write extension to that. However it's unpredictable and may produce strange behaviors.